# Unable to run node js code in visual studio code using code runner plugin

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

When I am trying to run node js code in visual studio code. I am getting below error.

Object Expected. Code 800A138F.
Source : Microsot JScript runtime error.

Note: I am using Windows 10 and visual studio code and code runner plugin

[Error Image- Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdSRn.png)

Comment: do you have the nodejs runtime installed?

Comment: yes I have node js runtime and I am able to run it from terminal

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded to powershell7 and I am able to run nodejs code using coder runner plugin.
[Code Runner with out error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pBiE.png)